# break-after: always; and flexbox in Chrome not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to do the effect shown below in a Webkit-based browser? In Firefox `break-after: always;` works and breaks the column but not in Chrome.

[image]

```css
.break {
  break-after: always;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 75%;
}

#columns {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

.testcl {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #4B5257;
  margin: 7px 10px;
}

.testcl h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 90%
}

.testcl ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1.8em
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="columns">
    <div class="testcl">
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div class="testcl">
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div class="testcl">
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div class="testcl">
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you write row instead of column, the boxes come side by side. flex-flow: row wrap;

Comment: I suggest you check the support before you use on [link](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_break-after_paged_context_always) and I think using basic responsive layout will be better for your case. check here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float)